# How to check the lag of a consumer in Kafka which is assigned with a particular partition of a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to check the lag for a consumer group which was assigned manually to particular topic , is this possible ? . I am using Kafka - 0.10.0.1 .I used sh kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand —new-consumer —describe —bootstrap-server localhost:9092 —group test but it says no group exists , so i wonder when we assign a partition manually can we check the lag for the consumer.

Comment: Later version is able to show the lags even for standalone consumers.

Answer (score 1):

In Nussknacker we are using [AKHQ](https://akhq.io/) GUI tool which provides various monitoring options as consumer and consumer groups lag and general Kafka operations as topic, topic data and schema registry management

Answer (score 0):

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
>   --describe --group

.

If You want API support or visual lag monitoring you can use https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

Comment: even that did not help

Comment: So are you saving your offset data on zookeeper or on kafka broker ? Is your consumer running ?

Comment: offset in kafka and yes consumer is running and i am using consumer.assign() for consuming from particular partition of a topic

Comment: Can you directly query __consumer-offset to check group and consumers. You can use this link https://www.ctheu.com/2017/08/07/looking-at-kafka-s-consumers-offsets/